# Google Drive (Backup and Sync) local folder no longer opens from Run

Tags: windows-explorer, google-drive, run-dialog, google-backup-and-sync

For some reason, `Google Drive` **as well as** the full directory path seems to no longer open the local folder (i.e., via `explorer.exe`) and instead triggers a system dialogue prompt to ask for file association.

Since there isn't any file extension that represents a folder — nor am I certain it would be correct for this case if there *were* one — I tried simply selecting both 1) `googledrivesync.exe`, as well as 2) `explorer.exe`.  While this does successfully launch the folder, it seems the system does not learn the selection, as the problem is still persistent.  Searching through here and Google didn't net any results (I'm a bit stumped as how to search `Run` disambiguously).

Any ideas on what's going on?  Here's my system specs, if that helps:
[image: System Specs]

EDIT: Screenshot for clarity:
[image: Screenshot]
Also, I've just noticed that while `Backup and Sync` is actively running as a process, the folder opens normally.  It appears to only occur when program is not running, even though it's just a regular directory.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Google Drive?

Comment: I will do so if nothing comes up, but I tend to not favor doing so as 1) it doesn't account for the root cause, and 2) no preventative measures are implemented, so even if it works as a corrective action, it's likely the same issue will occur again ceteris paribus.

Comment: Google drives updates it’s directory path on an automatic update if I understand the question correctly I had the same issue on a question I had on my profile and it has an answer

Comment: @SQLTemp I think I'm having a different issue, but thanks for the input.